# PHP MySQL INNER JOIN stops working after first cycle

Tags: php, mysql, inner-join

This works perfectly if album = 1,  but after that refuses to complete the query.

```
function findThumbnail($album, $photo) {

    echo 'Variable Check : Album ='.$album.' & PHOTO = '.$photo; // this always works

$thumbQuery =   "SELECT albums.*, photos.*
            FROM photos
            INNER JOIN albums 
            ON photos.album_id = albums.album_id
            WHERE photos.album_id = $album AND photos.photo_id = $photo 
            "; 

    $thumbResult = mysql_query($thumbQuery);

    while($thumbData = mysql_fetch_array($thumbResult))
        {       
          $photo_filename = $thumbData['photo_filename'];   
          $album_directory = $thumbData['album_directory'];   
        }

        $thumbAddress = 'photos/'.$album_directory.'/thumbs/'.$photo_filename.'.jpg';

        return $thumbAddress;     


}
```

I can't see it. Anyone?

---

**UPDATE**

(and thank you all for being kind with the new guy)

I'm not sure how I can be more specific with the query (putting in any number other than 1 for the $album causes it to fail), but the error is as follows:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: album_directory in functions.php on line 80
```

line 80 being

```
$thumbAddress = 'photos/'.$album_directory.'/thumbs/'.$photo_filename.'.jpg';
```

The relevant tables are as follows

```
+----------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field          | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| photo_id       | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| photo_filename | text    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| album_id       | int(10) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| photo_caption  | text    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+----------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

+----------------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field                | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| album_id             | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| album_year           | int(2)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| album_month          | int(2)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| album_day            | int(2)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| album_status         | int(2)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| album_caption        | text    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| album_location       | text    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| album_title          | text    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| album_directory      | text    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| album_cover_filename | text    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+----------------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

And to answer the 'how many' question, it should return one. I'm not familiar with the term *cargo cult programming* but then I'm not familiar with much at the moment.

Thank you for your time comments!

Comment: You need to paste the exact query that you are running, as well as the exact error message you receive when you run it.

Comment: If problem is with data (only works for value = 1 ), please, post some sample data (and descr tables).

Comment: How many rows should that query return? You're fetching the results into variables in a loop, and overwriting the previous row's data with the new row. If you're only expecting a single row, using a while() loop for fetching is indicative of cargo cult programming.

Comment: As well, have you checked if the query is actually failing? `mysql_query(...) or die(mysql_error())` will tell you so (and why).

Comment: I've updated the question so as to be clearer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If no records are returned from your query, since you're not defining `$album_directory` outside of your while-loop, it wouldn't be set and you'd get the `Notice: Undefined variable: album_directory in functions.php on line 80` notice.

If your query is only supposed to return one result, consider adding a [`LIMIT 1`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/select.html) to the end of your query.  Along with that, rather than starting a while-loop when you're only expecting a single row, use the results from [`mysql_num_rows($thumbResult);`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php) to determine the actual number of rows returned, then use [`mysql_fetch_array($thumbResult);`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php) to get the data.

Comment: If you use `mysql_num_rows` you also could use `LIMIT 2` instead of `LIMIT 1`. That allows you to throw an exception (or do something similar) in case there is more than 1 result.

Comment: @Crontab & Arjan : Thank you for the tips (both very useful) - it turns out that the conflict was with my naming convention, which looped around for each album, making a photo_id/album_id match impossible after the first album. Now fixed! Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

So basically, the notice tells you your innerhalb while loop never executed. This being because of a faild query or empty result